# samlp:RequestAbstractType - Trying to understand the ExtensionsType

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

According to SAML 2.0, a `RequestAbstractType` is defined in the following way:

```
<complexType name="RequestAbstractType" abstract="true">
    <sequence>
        <element ref="saml:Issuer" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element ref="ds:Signature" minOccurs="0"/>
        <element ref="samlp:Extensions" minOccurs="0"/>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="ID" type="ID" use="required"/>
    <attribute name="Version" type="string" use="required"/>
    <attribute name="IssueInstant" type="dateTime" use="required"/>
    <attribute name="Destination" type="anyURI" use="optional"/>
    <attribute name="Consent" type="anyURI" use="optional"/>
</complexType>
```

What I'm interested in is the `Extensions` element, which is defined as:

```
<element name="Extensions" type="samlp:ExtensionsType"/>

<complexType name="ExtensionsType">
    <sequence>
        <any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

How would I add/implement such an extension? I have no clue how to `extend` the RequestAbstractType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  element allows you to include anything you want within it.  Adding and processing of any data within that element would depend on your SAML product.

To give you an example of how it's used, here's a spec that leveraged it: http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/SpecDrafts-Post2.0/sstc-saml-protocol-ext-rac.pdf